# How to include a sas file embedded in my project?

Tags: sas

I am using SAS EP 4.1 and create SAS programs embedded in a project. Now I want to write %include statements to include the programs. How can I write the statement to point to those embedded files?

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the programs as .sas files and then you can include them. you probably need the full path in your %include.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types:

1. You can define a Fileref and provide that Fileref to %include statement.

> Filename macrodir 'c:\maclib\globtxt.sas';
>   %include macrodir;

2. You can provide the physical path of the SAS code to %include statement directly.

> %include 'c:\maclib\globtxt.sas';